# Bootstrap menu javascript function not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have a bootstrap menu which slidesdown using the following Jquery, it works in everything but IE8. Does anyone have any suggestion how to get this to work in IE8? thanks

```
(function ($, window, delay) {
  var theTimer = 0;
  var theElement = null;
    var theLastPosition = {x:0,y:0};
  $('.dropdown')
    .closest('li')
    .on('mouseenter', function (inEvent) {
    if (theElement) theElement.find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp();
    if (theElement) theElement.removeClass('open');
    window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
    theElement = $(this);

    theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
      theElement.find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown();
      theElement.addClass('open');
    }, delay);
  })
    .on('mousemove', function (inEvent) {
        if(Math.abs(theLastPosition.x - inEvent.ScreenX) > 4 || 
           Math.abs(theLastPosition.y - inEvent.ScreenY) > 4)
        {
            theLastPosition.x = inEvent.ScreenX;
            theLastPosition.y = inEvent.ScreenY;
            return;
        }

    if (theElement.hasClass('open')) return;
    window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
    theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
      theElement.find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown();
      theElement.addClass('open');
    }, delay);
  })
    .on('mouseleave', function (inEvent) {
    window.clearTimeout(theTimer);
    theElement = $(this);
    theTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
      theElement.find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp();
      theElement.removeClass('open');
    }, delay);
  });
})(jQuery, window, 200);
```

Comment: Bootstrap is not fully supported on IE8: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs are u including Responde.js ?

Comment: Hi, I've included html5shiv.j and respond.min.js, the menu didn't appear before I added these. I think the issue is with the mouseenter, mousemove and mouseleave events I don't think IE recognises them but am not 100% if this is true or how to fix it for IE8

Comment: what does the console error say in the browser??

Comment: There's no error, it just doesn't slidedown the menu when you mouseover the navigation.

Comment: The code works in IE9+ chrome and firefox

Comment: Ok, got it to work in IE8 now there was a conflict with a different bit of script. The only issue I have now is the dropdown doesn't stay open if I move the mouse off the main nav heading into the dropdown it closes. Any suggestions to correct this?

Comment: Ok got it fixed now, I changed the on to bind and now it works properly.